# How to convert a buffer to an image src in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, buffer

I have an image that's fed from an api in the form of a buffer. 
Specifically it looks like this:
[image]

I need to make the image show up in an actual image tag on the src attribute. So I am taking the data property of that object and passing it to another function that does the following:

```
let new_image= 'data:image/png;base64,' + btoa(image);

$('.preview_container img').attr('src', new_image);
```

This isn't working. I've tried sticking the data array directly into the src tag and that doesn't show anything. Is there a way to convert that byte array to something more usable?

Comment: Try to convert buffer to string first, `btoa(String(image))` or `btoa(image.toString())` or if this buffer is Node.js Buffer just do `image.toString("base64")`

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("YourImage").src = "data:image/png;base64," + YourByte;
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work. The weird thing is that I can see the converted array on the src attr in the actual html, but the image is just not there (0x0) so I assume it's some kind of encoding issue.